# Is AWS RDS interface endpoint required if the rds is created in the private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, endpoint

If I create an RDS in the private network, AWS gives an endpoint like: `dbsvr-XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.<region>.rds.amazonaws.com`
and this endpoint is resolvable.
Then what's the benefit of an RDS interface endpoint?
When I create an interface endpoint for RDS, AWS gives an endpoint like: `rds.<region>.amazonaws.com`

Why the endpoint of a database instance has a domain suffix `<region>.rds.amazonaws.com` while the interface endpoint has a domain of `rds.<region>.amazonaws.com`? What's the difference between these two domain suffix?

Comment: One's for the RDS database instance/cluster that you created in your VPC and you use it to establish a connection to the DB and make queries. The other (the VPC interface endpoint) relates to the RDS service itself (if you want to make API requests over non-public network routes to the RDS service in order to manage RDS resources).

Comment: It is rare that you'll need to use an RDS interface endpoint, since it is just used to 'manage' the database (eg change configuration) from within the VPC. It is _not_ used to 'connect' to the database and run SQL.

Comment: @jarmod, if `<region>.rds.amazonaws.com` is for database, and `rds.<region>.amazonaws.com` is for database service, why S3 doesn't have the same pattern? for s3, both the service itself and the api goes to the same `s3.<region>.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Not sure I can answer why. An internal AWS decision, perhaps to simplify DNS ownership and management. An RDS instance/cluster hostname is an alias for the relevant active EC2 instance that's hosting the database server. If you dig the RDS hostname, you should see a CNAME record.